# Involution on Cantor space with exactly one fixed point

Tags: general-topology, logic, group-actions

Let $X=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ be the Cantor space. What is an example of a continuous map $\sigma : X \to X$ with $\sigma^2=\mathrm{id}$ and $\# \{x \in X : \sigma(x)=x\} = 1$?

This has to exist, since $X$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$ by Brouwer's Theorem, and there we can take $x \mapsto -x$.

Comment: Let $\varphi : X \to \mathbb{Z}_p$ be a homeomorphism, and define $f(x) = \varphi^{-1}(-\varphi(x))$? :)

Comment: More seriously, as far as I remember it's possible to find a very explicit homeomorphism $\varphi$, so simply computing the composition should give an "explicit" formula.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that there is an explicit homeomorphism. Maybe someone can write it down and then $\sigma$ in an answer.

Comment: The trick is to define a homeo $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N} \to \{0,1,\dots,p-1\}^\mathbb{N}$, and then it's easy. I'm still trying to work out this first homeo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define $\sigma:(x_1,x_2,\dots)\mapsto(y_1,y_2,\dots)$ so that 
$y_n=x_n\Leftrightarrow x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{n-1}=0$.

In words, flip everything after the first $1$.

Comment: I don't understand this; how is $y_n$ defined?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg $y_n\in\{0,1\}$, and $y_n=x_n$ if and only if $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{n-1}$ are all zero.

Comment: $$y_n=x_n\text{ if }x_1+\cdots+x_{n-1}=0$$$$y_n=1-x_n\text{ if }x_1+\cdots+x_{n-1}\gt0$$

Comment: @bof: +1 Wonderful!  $$(0,0,0,\color{red}1, \color{blue}0,\color{blue}1,\color{blue}0,\color{blue}0,\color{blue}1,\ldots )\mapsto (0,0,0,\color{red}1, \color{green}1,\color{green}0,\color{green}1,\color{green}1,\color{green} 0,\ldots )$$

Comment: In fact you only need to flip some piece after the first $1$, it could vary with the position of the first $1$ or uniformly, like flip the next term.

Comment: @orangeskid Oh, right. But that makes the definition more complicated, doesn't it?$$y_n=1-x_n\Longleftrightarrow n\gt1\wedge x_{n-1}=1\wedge x_1+\cdots+x_{n-2}=0$$:-)

Comment: It makes the definition only more complicated when you want to hide it within a formula which one doesn't understand immediately. I really like the word-definitions here.

Comment: May I ask a bonus question? Is there some open subset $U$ of the Cantor space $X$ such that $X \setminus \{0\} = U \coprod \sigma(U)$? Perhaps $U = \{(0,0,\dotsc,0,1,1,?,\dotsc)\}$?

Comment: The word-definition is great: flip (something!) after the first $1$

Comment: Your $U$ looks fine to me. (I assume you're using @orangeskid's simpler version of $\sigma$ where only the next bit after the first $1$ is flipped. It looks harder with my original $\sigma$.)

Comment: Oh, you're right. Is there some $U$ with your $\sigma$?

Comment: Oh. Same $U$ works with my $\sigma$, doesn't it? Don't know what I was thinking. Maybe I need some coffee.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the homeomorphism from $\{0,2,3\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ to $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$
 mapping a sequence $(a_n)$ to the concatenation of binary writings of the $a_n$'s.

Comment: Okay. I was trying to find another bijection and mixed up the two in my head, sorry for the confusion :) Mine ended up being the same as yours, though.

Comment: All these encodings are easier to see with binary trees. The infinite rooted binary tree whose infinite paths from the root correspond to sequences of $0$ and $1$ can be broken up into finite rooted binary trees that are not $\Lambda$ but have several (more than two if needed) ends. Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding

Comment: Ah nice, I hadn't made the connection. I was trying to work by blocks at first (mapping blocks of three to blocks of two for example), but it became clear that the image blocks couldn't be of fixed length ($\gcd(2,3) = 1$...).

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\N{\mathbb{N}}$Let $p=3$ for simplicity (what follows could work for any $p$, not that we really need it). First we define a homeomorphism $f : \{0,1,2\}^\N \to \{0,1\}^\N$. $f(x)$ is defined by concatenating the $\varphi(x_n)$ where:
$$\varphi(u) = \begin{cases}
(0) & u = 0 \\
(1,0) & u = 1 \\
(1,1) & u = 2
\end{cases}$$
This is continuous: we need to check that the preimage of $\{x | x_n = k \}$ (where $k,i$ are fixed) is open, but there's only a finite number of beginning of sequences satisfying that. The inverse map is defined "inductively": if we see a zero we add a zero to the image, otherwise if we see $1*$ we add either $1$ or $2$. The map is therefore bijective, and since both spaces are compact (Tychonoff) and Hausdorff, this is a homeomorphism.

Now the map $\{0,1,2\}^\N \to \mathbb{Z}_3$ defined by $x \mapsto \sum_n x_n 3^n$ is a homeomorphism (it's easy, I won't prove it but I won't actually need it), which lets us intuit the involution. Define $\sigma : \{0,1,2\}^\N \to \{0,1,2\}^\N$ by:
$$\sigma(x)_n = \begin{cases}
0 & x_n = 0 \\
2 & x_n = 1 \\
1 & x_n = 2
\end{cases}$$
This corresponds to $y \mapsto -y$ on $\mathbb{Z}_3$. Then $\sigma$ is a self-homeomorphism (bijective is obvious, each component map is the composite of a projection and $(12) \in \mathfrak{S}_2$, finally both spaces are compact Hausdorff so it's a homeomorphism), and the zero sequence is the only fixpoint. Finally $f \sigma f^{-1}$ is the involution we wanted.